# How does Python turn a function into a method?

Tags: python

I know that functions are just descriptors, like this:

```
def func(self):
    print(self.name)


class C:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


C.func = func
c = C("foo")
c.func()
```

I thought at first that `c.func` equals `C.func.__get__(c)`，yes，`C.func.__get__(c)` return a bound method. But when I set the `__get__` of func to None, `c.func` still returns a bound method.

```
def func(self):
    print(self.name)


class C:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


func.__get__ = None
C.func = func
c = C("foo")
c.func
```

output:

```
<bound method func of <__main__.C object at 0x0000027EB23BF088>>
```

So I'm confused. Moreover, I found that when calling a function from an instance, Python actually calls the class's `___getAttribute__` method, which returns a bound method.

```
def func(self):
    print(self.name)

func.__get__ = None

class C:
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        r = super().__getattribute__(name)
        print(r)  # r is a bound method already
        return r
        
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


C.func = func
c = C("foo")
c.func
```

output:

```
<bound method func of <__main__.C object at 0x0000027EB243D1C8>>
```

`func.__get__` doesn't seem to have any effect. So, What happended in `__getattribute__`? How does Python turn a function into a method? I've Googled and done some research, but I still can't find the answer.

Maybe I'm making things complicated, In my understanding, function is itself a descriptor, but just like the code below, I set the `func` to `None`, it works normally:

```
class C:
    def func(self):
        print('hello world')
        
    func.__get__ = None


c = C()
c.func()
```

but if it's a descriptor, it will raise `TypeError`:

```
class C:
    class D:
        def __get__(self, inst, cls):
            if inst is None:
                return self
            return 'hello world'

    D.__get__ = None

    func = D()


c = C()
c.func
```

Comment: Maybe this can answer your question: https://medium.com/@satishgoda/python-attribute-access-using-getattr-and-getattribute-6401f7425ce6

Comment: Thanks a lot @Geekmoss. But I'm still confused.It looks like `super().__getattribute__` turns `func` into `bound method`, but I don't know how this happens, because if it were a normal descriptor, it would call its `__get__` method, but it doesn't seem to call the `__get__` of func. I set the `__get__` of func to None, but it still returns a bound method.

Comment: I tried to answer below, I hope this answers your question.

Comment: You can't override magic methods at instance level - Python will completely ignore your "override".

Comment: ⊙︿⊙, I understand, thank you @user2357112 supports Monica

Answer (score -1):

Well, if I understand correctly from what I found. (Since I didn't know the descriptors, that's exactly why I like to help, still learning)

First, let's look at `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`.

Let's have an empty class `A`

```py
class A:
     pass
```

If I initialize an object and try to call a property, because there is none at the moment, we get `AttributeError`.

```py
a = A()
a.some_property
```

The following occurs:
[image: Python, get attribute flow]

Simple check of flow:

```py
class FlowDemo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inited_property = True


    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item in ('__class__', '__len__') :  # For less spam of getting this attribute, if you want, you can remove condition.
            print('Get Attribute', item)
        # Call default behavior
        return super().__getattribute__(item)


    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print('Get Attr', item)
        if item == 'some_magic_name':
            return "It's magic!"
        raise AttributeError
```

```py
fd = FlowDemo()

fd.inited_property
# Get Attribute inited_property
# True

fd.some_magic_property
# Get Attribute some_magic_name
# Get Attr some_magic_name
# "It's magic!"

fd.some_property
# Get Attribute some_property
# Get Attr some_property
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
#  File "stack-class-property-and-descriptors.py", line 67, in # __getattr__
#    raise AttributeError
# AttributeError
```

This is probably understandable, including the use. But to be sure, I'll give an example. This logic is used as a dynamic representation of the result from the databases (mapping of attributes to ordinary dict, list, etc.).

But it can also be just logic for accessing an attribute (property), such as an access counter or validation (but this applies to `__setattr__` and `__setattribute__`)

**And what about descriptors?**

First let's look at data-descriptors, they are easier for me to understand.
This is a class or decoder that has `__get__` and one or both of `__set__` and `__delete__`.

Once this is defined, python, when used in the property definition with it and then does not return a class but the value it obtains through `__get__`, does not overwrite an already declared class when declaring a value, but uses its `__set__`.

Example:

```py
class WeekDayDescriptor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__week_day = 0
        

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        return self.__week_day
    

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError('Value must be int')
        if not (0 <= value < 6):
            raise ValueError('Value must be in range 0 - 6')
        self.__week_day = value



class Calendar:
    week_day = WeekDayDescriptor()

    def __init__(self, week_day):
        self.week_day = week_day
```

Demo:

```py
c = Calendar(9)
# ValueError: Value must be in range 0-6

c = Calendar('6')
# TypeError: Value must be int

c = Calendar(3)
c.week_day = 6

c.week_day = 10
# ValueError: Value must be in range 0-6

c.week_day = 'monday'
# TypeError: Value must be int
```

Decorator descriptor:

```py
class Calendar:
    @property
    def week_day(self):
        return self.__week_day
    
    @week_day.setter
    def week_day(self, week_day):
        if not isinstance(week_day, int):
            raise TypeError('Value must be int')
        if not (0 <= week_day < 6):
            raise ValueError('Value must be in range 0 - 6')
        self.__week_day = week_day

    def __init__(self, week_day):
        self.week_day = week_day
    pass
```

And now for non-data descriptors...

A non-data descriptor is one that has only `__get__`.
As I understand it, each method automatically has its own descriptor, thanks to which the functions get references to the object - `self`.

We can write our own descriptor for a function / method, but it's not that straightforward, we have to help ourselves and get around it a bit.

```py
def function_as_method(self, value):
    print(self, value)

class HelperDescriptor:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return function_as_method(instance, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

class Foo:
    baz = HelperDescriptor()

>>> bar = Foo()
>>> bar.baz(1)
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f64f7768b70> 1
```

*[Source of last code block, but in czech lang.](https://blog.milde.cz/post/319-pokrocile-techniky-v-pythonu-deskriptory/)*

---

And finally, your mentioned problem, when we set `__get__` to `None` and you still get a reference to the function.

It's simple, python doesn't directly distinguish between primitive data types and functions, it's all a variable (or attribute / property) that has a value. Whether it's just value or it's callable is a different matter.

```py
def f(): return True
print(type(f), f())
# <class 'function'> True

f = 123
print(type(f), f)
# <class 'int'> 123
```

Therefore, when we ask for the `obj.func` method or call it `obj.func()` directly, the first two changed magic is called first - `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__`.
And if we call a method, it is called only after we get a reference to a function in memory.

Again a simple example:

```py
def func(self, value):
    print('Printing:', value)


class PrintDescriptor:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"Calling '{self.name}' method")
            return func(instance, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper


class B:
    foo = PrintDescriptor('foo')
    bar = PrintDescriptor('bar')

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item not in ('__len__', '__class__', '__dict__'):
            print('Get Attribute', item)

        return super().__getattribute__(item)
```

Demo:

```py
b = B()

b.foo
# Get Attribute foo
# <function PrintDescriptor.__get__.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f774a782ee0>

b.foo(2)
# Get Attribute foo
# Calling 'foo' method
# Printing: 2

b.bar(4)
# Get Attribute bar
# Calling 'bar' method
# Printing: 4
```

Sources:

- https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-descriptors#above1
- https://blog.milde.cz/post/319-pokrocile-techniky-v-pythonu-deskriptory/
- [Python Doc, `__get__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__get__#object.__get__)
- [Python Docs, `__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__get__#object.__getattribute__)
- [Python Docs, `__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__get__#object.__getattr__)

Comment: Thank you again, @Geekmoss. But I still don't quite understand, I edited my post again and added some code, my English is not very good, I hope I made myself clear.